# Cloud Spanner: Case-insensitive query goes extremely slow even when indexed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions/case-insensitive-search

This page describes the problem I'm having and a potential solution.

To summarize the issue, I want to get all results matching a query using `where UPPER(some_column) = UPPER(@param)`. I have an index that returns <50ms if I don't use `UPPER` on `some_column`. The same query takes 4+ seconds with the `UPPER` since the table is indexed on `some_column` alone and not the `UPPER` value of that column.

The author proposed this:

> To support that query, we need an index that covers the actual search
>   term. That means we do not need an index on LAST_NAME but on
>   UPPER(LAST_NAME):
>
> `CREATE INDEX emp_up_name 
>       ON employees (UPPER(last_name))`
>
> An index whose definition contains functions or expressions is a
>   so-called function-based index (FBI). Instead of copying the column
>   data directly into the index, a function-based index applies the
>   function first and puts the result into the index. As a result, the
>   index stores the names in all caps notation.

Does Spanner support a way to do this? If not what is a good alternative?

I've tried created a function-based index like this, but there's a syntax error making me think functions aren't allowed in the Cloud Spanner DDL

`CREATE INDEX some_index 
ON Table (
    UPPER(Type)
)`

Answer (score 1):

As you said it's not possible to use `UPPER` in Cloud Spanner DDL, as it's not supported.

You can raise a feature request for that following this link [[1]](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901).

The only workaround I can think of is changing the data before so it's already in uppercase.